# Oracle case for null

Tags: sql, oracle, null, case

I was searching for this one for a pretty long time and went through several similar questions on this web but couldn't get my query solved. i have a stored procedure in which i have a parameter SP_BRANCH_ID, i want a case that if it is null then fkBranchId = null  in my table gets retrieved or else the the ones specified in Sp_branch_id.

```
PROCEDURE USP_GET_TAX_RATES_BY_ID(SP_CURSOR OUT T_CURSOR,SP_BRANCH_ID IN NUMBER)
IS 
BEGIN 
   OPEN SP_CURSOR FOR
      SELECT "TaxRates".* from "TaxRates" where "IsDeleted" = 'N' AND "fkBranchId" =(
         case when  SP_BRANCH_ID is null then null else (SP_BRANCH_ID) end );
END USP_GET_TAX_RATES_BY_ID;
```

Comment: we can do this with help of nvl itself Eg:nvl(sp_branch_id,null). Why you need case here?

Comment: because from front end if i didnt select any branch , null will go in db

Comment: Thats okay...to check the presence of null NVL would be suffice. Did you try with the help of nvl in your where clause?

Comment: yes it didnt retrieve anything

Comment: @Sana, NULL is never equal to anything, neither equal to NULL. It is tri valued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the null check with a string

```
SELECT "TaxRates".* from "TaxRates"
   WHERE "IsDeleted" = 'N'
   and NVL("fkBranchId" ,'null')=NVL(SP_BRANCH_ID,'null');
```

Answer (score 2):

When the SP_BRANCH_ID is null , you are assigning `"fkBranchId" = NULL`, which is wrong usage in Oracle.

Use `IS NULL` for null checks.

```
PROCEDURE USP_GET_TAX_RATES_BY_ID(SP_CURSOR OUT T_CURSOR,SP_BRANCH_ID IN NUMBER)
IS 
BEGIN 
   OPEN SP_CURSOR FOR
      SELECT "TaxRates".* from "TaxRates"
       WHERE "IsDeleted" = 'N'
       AND ( "fkBranchId" = SP_BRANCH_ID OR (SP_BRANCH_ID IS NULL AND "fkBranchId" IS NULL))
END USP_GET_TAX_RATES_BY_ID;
```

Comment: Good point Mahesh +1. @OP should know how the tri-valued `NULL` is interpreted in Oracle. Anything equal to NULL is meaningless. I wish Oracle removes the dilemma between an empty string and NULL.